# billSafe payment module not show in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

i have installed PrestaShop™ 1.4.7.3

i download the module BillSafe from http://www.billsafe.de/

I configure all the setting from prestashop backEnd but the billSafe module not display on front side

what is the issue that module not display on front ???

Comment: have you checked if it is correctly attached to a hook?

Comment: @Anila Yes it correctly attachted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every module in Prestashop is hook with the position ,

For specific module like BillSafe- Payment Module it have min and max value of payment, if EndUser select the product between those value , BillSafe is shown on the payment page